# Error: because example depends on package/project from hosted on [URL], version solving failed.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I had an error in project Flutter and I don't know how to fix that. this error occurs when I command `flutter pub get` run

Error:

> SLVR:   derived: json_annotation ^4.4.0 SLVR:   conflict: package_base
> 1.22.025+9 depends on package_context ^1.21.353+4 SLVR:   ! package_base 1.22.025+9 is partially satisfied by not package_base
>
> > 1.22.025+9 <2.0.0 SLVR:   ! which is caused by "no versions of package_base match >1.22.025+9 <2.0.0" SLVR:   ! thus: package_base
> > ^1.22.025+9 requires package_context ^1.21.353+4 SLVR:   !
> > package_base ^1.22.025+9 is satisfied by package_base ^1.22.025+9
> > SLVR:   ! which is caused by "package_identity depends on package_base
> > ^1.22.025+9" SLVR:   ! thus: package_context ^1.21.353+4 is required
> > SLVR:   ! not package_context ^1.21.353+4 is satisfied by
> > package_context ^1.21.353+4 SLVR:   ! which is caused by
> > "package_identity depends on package_context ^1.21.353+4" SLVR:   !
> > thus: version solving failed SLVR: Version solving took 0:00:04.357063
> > seconds.
> > | Tried 1 solutions. FINE: Resolving dependencies finished (4.4s). ERR : Because package_base 1.22.025+9 depends on package_context
> > ^1.21.353+4 and no versions of package_base match >1.22.025+9 <2.0.0,
> > package_base ^1.22.025+9 requires package_context from hosted on
> > [http://2.1.2.9:500/[token]/](http://2.1.2.9:500/%5Btoken%5D/).
> > | So, because package_identity depends on both package_base ^1.22.025+9 and package_context from hosted on
> > [http://2.1.2.9:500/[token]/](http://2.1.2.9:500/%5Btoken%5D/), version solving failed. FINE: Exception
> > type: SolveFailure FINE: package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart
> > 312:5                 VersionSolver._resolveConflict
> > | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 133:27                VersionSolver._propagate
> > | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:11                 VersionSolver.solve.
> > | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
> > | dart:async                                                       Future.catchError
> > | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:52                                captureErrors.wrappedCallback
> > | package:stack_trace                                              Chain.capture
> > | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                                captureErrors
> > | package:pub/src/command.dart 180:13                              PubCommand.run
> > | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27                          CommandRunner.runCommand
> > | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 173:24                       PubCommandRunner.runCommand
> > | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 158:20                       PubCommandRunner.run
> > | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56                               runDartdev
> > | C:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\sdk\pkg\dartdev\bin\dartdev.dart 11:9  main
> > ---- End log transcript ---- pub get failed (1; ---- End log transcript ----) Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore Run
> > Attachments will be stored in LogStore No Result Found to Publish
> > 'D:\a\1\s\junit.xml'.
> > ##[error]Some tests failed

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1466], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are waiting for a solution, here it is:

**Solution 1:**
The simplest solution if you are doing some important and deadline work and you don't want to take any risk, you can use an **older version of Flutter only**.
If you have already upgraded Flutter 2, You can downgrade the older version using `flutter downgrade`
Note: Must try everything on new or older Flutter after taking a backup of your project.

**Solution 2:**

If you are just learning and not doing any deadline work then you can try this option because it's all about trial-n-error.

Use a new section in `pubspec.yaml` named `dependency_overrides:` [Documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides)

**You can use **`dependency_overrides`** to temporarily override all references to a dependency.**

Here is the older version of my `pubspec.yaml` which is working before upgrading Flutter 2. I got the errors in as it is pubspec after upgrading Flutter 2. After trying for 2 days I got a solution using dependency_overrides.
And finally here is the new `pubspec.yaml`, In which you can check some dependency added to dependency_overrides.

**How to do it:**

You can check which dependency is dependent on another dependency. You can write that dependency in dependency_overrides:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_auth: “>=1.0.0”
  firebase_core: “>=0.7.0”
  firebase_messaging: “>=8.0.0-dev.14”
  firebase_remote_config: “>=0.6.0”
  firebase_auth_web: “>=0.2.0” 
  firebase: “>=7.0.0”
  flutter_local_notifications: “>=4.0.0”
```

As of now, At the time of writing this blog, It is working for me, you can change version changes as per your needs.

> **Warning**: Using a dependency override involves some risk. For example,
> using an override to specify a version outside the range that the
> package claims to support, or using an override to specify a local
> copy of a package that has unexpected behaviors, may break your
> application.

Hopefully, someone will get help or clue from it.
If you have any questions, free feel to ping me any time.

refresnce:
https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b